# C#. Windows Service. Подтекает память

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, windows-service

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком месте я допустил ошибку, что служба постепенно поджирает память

Задача службы при старте загружать построчно адреса из файла Services.txt в `List<Uri>` и через определенный интервал делать GET-запрос по каждому URL из файла

***Program.cs***

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = {
            new ServicePusher()
        };

        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

***ServicePusher.cs***

```
public partial class ServicePusher : ServiceBase
{
    private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private Timer ServiceTimer;
    private readonly List<Uri> ServiceUrl = new List<Uri>();

    public ServicePusher()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Services.txt"))
        {
            Log.Error("Не найден Services.txt");
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Не найден Services.txt");
        }

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Services.txt"))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Uri serviceUri = null;

                try
                {
                    serviceUri = new Uri(line);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error($"Ошибка при получении адреса сервиса ({line}): {ex}");
                }

                if (serviceUri != null)
                {
                    ServiceUrl.Add(serviceUri);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Error($"Некорректный адрес сервиса ({line}) в файле Services.txt");
                }
            }
        }

        ServiceTimer = new Timer
        {
            Interval = Config.Interval
        };

        ServiceTimer.Elapsed += Tick;
        ServiceTimer.AutoReset = true;
        ServiceTimer.Start();


        Log.Info("Сервис успешно запущен");
        Log.Info($"Загружено сервисов: {ServiceUrl.Count}");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        ServiceTimer.Stop();
        ServiceTimer.Dispose();
        ServiceTimer = null;

        Log.Info("Сервис остановлен");
    }

    private void Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Uri url in ServiceUrl)
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (o, a, b, c) => true;

                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Proxy = null;
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Timeout = 360000;
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                try
                {
                    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (Stream requestStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            if (requestStream == null)
                            {
                                Log.Error($"Нет ответа от {url}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error($"Ошибка ({ex.Message}) при запросе к сервису {url}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD:** отжирает примерно по 2 мб в час

**UPD 2:** обновил код в вопросе, за 15 минут стабильно жрет ~350 кб...

Может дело в **Program.cs**?

Comment: Такое количество Using в моменте получения ответа от сервера  не нужно. Я не знаю как работает внутри ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback, может он где то в статике хранит доверенные сертификаты и не чистится. Потому, что в целом вроде все так!

Comment: @YuryBakharev а чем using-то плохи, хуже же они не сделают?

Comment: using -хороши, но в вашем примере - избыточны.

Comment: @tCode, а что творится во втором using? `using ((HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())`?

Comment: @Grundy приведение к типу объекта,  который уже не используется),  но вряд ли это влияет на проблему

Comment: @Grundy да, это остатки фичи, которая проверяла код ответа... удалил ее, а using забыл

Comment: @Grundy, а что будет если я после самого последнего catch добавлю finally с GC.Collect()?

Comment: @tCode, скорее всего - ничего не будет :) А в вопросе полный код? или со скаченным содержимым дальше какие-то действия еще?

Comment: @Grundy в вопросе код полный, служба тупо дергает сервисы, чтобы они поднялись на IIS

Comment: тут нужен какой-нибудь профилировщик. Я не вижу, что бы могло увеличиваться по 2мб в час. Может не тот процесс смотрел? А ошибок при этом нет?

Comment: @Grundy, ошибок нет, процесс тот, в студии нельзя дебажиться в проекте windows service... так бы воспользовался стандартным профилировщиком, есть вариант перенести в консольное приложение и там попробовать

Comment: @tCode почему нельзя дебажить его? Неужели Attach to Process запретили?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем мои опасения оказались напрасны, оставил службу работать всю ночь, сейчас работает и использует всего 5 мб памяти

Но остается непонятным почему при запуске службы первое время она потребляет около 11 мб

Comment: Дотнет-приложениям изначально выделяется около дюжины мегабайт памяти под кучу. Полагаю, к сервисам это тоже относится. Ну, а в процессе работы, вероятно, незанятая память освобождается.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov видимо так, да