# Программа потребляет много cpu

Tags: c#

Небольшое отступление

У нас в фирме используется одна очень древняя программа с одним недостатком. После работы с ней надо чистить за ней файлы и в одном файле менять значения на первоначальные. Иначе при следующем запуске программа работает некорректно.

Итак решение - пишем программу в виде виндоуз формы, а потом форму удаляем, и кидаем ее в автозагрузку. В программе запущен таймер который проверяет если та древняя программа была закрыта пользователем он файлы приводит в первоначальный вид.

Но так форму я удалил (пользователям о ней знать не обязательно), что бы моя программа не завершала работу в ней стоит бесконечный цикл. Вот код:

```
private static void Main()
    {
TimerCallback timer= new TimerCallback(Run);

        System.Threading.Timer time = new System.Threading.Timer(timer, null, 0, 2000);    
for(;;)
}
static void Run(object state)
{....}
```

но как оказалось он потребляет 20-30 процентов ресурсов проца именно из за бесконечного цикла. Есть у кого нибудь идеи как уменьшить нагрузку на проц?

Да и не хотелось бы использовать форму пусть и полностью прозрачную.

Comment: А почему не тупо написать программу-враппер, которая будет запускать нужную программу и подчищать после неё?

Comment: напишите Windows Service - приложение, используя внутри таймер System.Timers.Timer, вот пример http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591163/c-windows-service-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: @tCode ответ про службу от **Yury Bakharev** уже присутствует и подвергся некоторой критике

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это у вас 3-4 ядра, вот оно и потребляет всего 20-30 процентов. Будет одно ядро - будет жрать 100, я думаю. Поставьте в этот цикл хотя бы Sleep(100) и будет счастье. А вообще надо нормально переписывать, а не костыли использовать...

Comment: Помогло, вместо таймера поставил

А по поводу программы ее еще под дос писали и переписывать точно не хотелось бы.

Comment: private static void Main() под DOS писали? Не верю

Comment: это другая программа под дос написана, а я за ней чищу.

Comment: Вот я про нее и говорю: не нужны формы и прочие костыли. Системный таймер и отсутствие гуя вам определенно помогут.

Comment: Вообще, в принципе, задача решабельна многими путями, например, 1. Через BAT/PowerShell - скрипт, к которому делается ярлык. Пользователь запускает скрипт, тот, в свою очередь, запускает DOS-программу и ждет ее завершения, по завершении - чистит нужные файлы и копирует файл с нужными значениями поверх измененного (ну или правит в этом файле значения на нужные).
2. Ровно то же самое - но через простое консольное приложение. Делается launcher, без всяких форм и окон (даже окно консоли можно скрыть), и для пользователя визуально нет никакой разницы.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [WaitForExit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx) и таймер вовсе не потребуется.

Comment: @BlackWitcher думаю стоит перенести из комментариев в самостоятельный ответ, идеально, если еще и пример скрипта приложите для первого варианта. Досовский софт, разного качества и назначения, все еще довольно часто встречается в бухгалтериях, и почти каждый пилит свой свой собственный костыль для него.

Comment: @rdorn, ответил, но написание скриптов на VBS и PowerShell требует времени, потому проиллюстрировал лишь BAT-файлом.

Answer (score 5):

Программа, которая "гоняет" вечный цикл - считается зависшей. Это - не самое лучшее решение.

Вот так будет чуть лучше:

```
Application.Run();
```

Метод `Run` без параметров запускает цикл обработки сообщений (что приведет к "засыпанию" главного потока) - но при этом не задает главную форму (позволяя программе работать без открытых форм). При этом программа не теряет возможности корректно обработать сообщение закрытия (например, при завершении сеанса пользователя).

Comment: @polsok оставить таймер и использовать этот вариант - самое красивое решение из  тех, что с минимумом действий

Comment: @polsok - я тоже настоятельно рекомендую обратить внимание на этот ответ (и используйте таймер).

Answer (score 3):

Одно из возможных решений для запуска старых DOS-программ (и не только их) и выполнения каких-то дополнительных действий — через скрипты, запуск которых с точки зрения пользователя будет выглядеть так же, как и запуск самой программы, только скрипт может выполнить еще и какие-то сопутствующий действия. Например, у автора вопроса нужно после выполнения программы удалять ряд файлов и менять значения параметров в одном из файлов.

Попробуем решить задачу при помощи скриптов.

Когда-то давно у меня был IBM PC 286 c EGA-монитором, 40Мб жестким 5-ти дюймовым диском (именно так, и еще 5" дисковод для НГМД), на котором работал MS-DOS 6.22 и Norton Commander 4.0. С тех пор еще немного помню как работать с [**BAT-файлами**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB), которые, впрочем, весьма ***часто*** и успешно используются и по сей день:

```
rem Отключаем вывод на экран:
@echo off 
rem Очищаем экран:
cls 
rem Переходим в папку с программой:
cd "C:\OLD_PRG\" 
rem Здесь можно выполнить запуск необходимых программ ДО запуска
rem основной программы, например, загрузить русификатор.
rem Если запустить его через команду start, то он запустится в отдельном окне.
rem Пример: start keyrus.com
rem Но нам русификация нужна в этой сессии, потому запускаем его так:
keyrus.com
rem Теперь запускаем нужную программу и ждем ее завершения:
start /wait OldPrg.exe
rem Программа завершилась, теперь можно удалить нужные файлы.
rem В данном примере это временные файлы *.tmp
del *.tmp
rem Восстановим файл настроек, для этого просто удалим измененный файл в
rem папке программы, а потом заменим эталонным из резервной копии, в
rem качестве которой у нас выступает подпапка BAK, находящаяся тут:
rem "C:\OLD_PRG\BAK", просто использую относительные пути:
del config.cfg
copy .\BAK\config.cfg config.cfg
rem Всё, теперь можно подождать нажатия любой кнопки, а затем выйти из сессии
pause
exit
```

Скрипт очень простой, приведен в качестве примера. На самом деле, можно многое что делать при помощи пакетных файлов.

Единственный минус - если создать ярлык к файлу напрямую, то при его запуске будет видно окно консоли, в котором запущен наш BAT-файл.
Это тоже решабельно, ибо есть утилиты, которые могут выполнять BAT-файл скрывая окно консоли, в котором он выполняется.

---

Так же можно выполнять скрипты на **PowerShell**, но поскольку по-умолчанию есть ограничение в политике Windows на выполнение таких скриптов, то рассматривать этот вариант я не буду. Если всё же очень интересно, то лучше это оформить как отдельный вопрос.

---

Можно так же вызывать скрипты на других языках, например, JavaScript, или Visual Basic Script.

---

И, как вариант, можно написать свою простенькую обертку вокруг чужого EXE, который можно запускать через `Process.Start` используя [WaitForExit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx). В частности, сам так делаю для работы с старым консольным архиватором ARJ.

---

Еще вариант для старых DOS-программ, это, разуммется, [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/).

Вот, в зависимости от ситуации, можно использовать разные подходы для решения обозначенного вопроса по запуску старых программ в современном окружении.

Comment: интересно кто влепил минус... простое и доступное решение даже для начинающего админа, далекого от языков программирования, но немного знакомого с консолью windows. И никаких проблем с потреблением ресурсов.

Comment: вот тут https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting хорошая шпаргалка по командам для BAT-скриптов.

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно написать сервис(службу Windows)класс ServiceBase в.net. Выложите код  где вы чистите файл. Из кода не понятно что у вас происходит, таймер вообще не используется.

Comment: Зачем службу? Это не задача службы, она не должна работать до логина. Задача для обычного приложения без гуя.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов  почему это не может делать служба?

Comment: Это может делать И служба тоже, но написание служб и их регистрация сложнее. То же самое можно и на уровне драйверов ФС делать, вопрос только зачем делать сложно, если можно делать проще?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну по мне так если что-то должно работать постоянно и не  требуется никаких  вмешательств пользователя и как я понял из фразы(пользователям о ней знать не обязательно) могут быть разные права у учетной записи, служба здесь подходит больше, а то что нужно прописать одну строчку в консоль это  небольшие энергозатраты, вам так не кажется?

Comment: Автостарта хватит. Службы имеют больше привелегий, чем тут надо.

Comment: Службы имеют столько, сколько им дадут.

Comment: не так уж и сложно служба пишется, вот устанавливается чуть сложнее чем закинуть приложение в автозапуск

Comment: @4per на самом деле служба устанавливается проще чем в автозапуск закинуть. `sc create {name} binpath={path}`. А для автозапуска надо еще ярлык создавать...

Comment: Скорее, проблема службы - в том, что ее не поставить без прав администратора.

Comment: @PavelMayorov но в данном то случае  права администратора есть!